# Cordova App breaks on Android 5.0

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

Cordova App breaks on Android lollipop, During app installation this is what i see in the logcat, though i am not sure if these are the actual cause of the error. (app installs/works fine on versions < 5.0)

using cordova v-5.1.1 & cordova-android@4.0.2

```
I/PersonaManagerService( 3485): PersonaId don't exist
I/ActivityManager( 3485): do not start freezing screen for locked container getKeyguardshowstate = false 
E/Parcel  ( 3485): Class not found when unmarshalling: com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics 
E/Parcel  ( 3485): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics
```

further downword in the logs i see this

```
D/ApplicationPolicy( 3485): isStatusBarNotificationAllowedAsUser: packageName = com.android.providers.downloads,userId = 0
V/ApplicationPolicy( 3485): isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.android.providers.downloads
W/NotificationService( 3485): Pray mode not found android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Application package com.sec.android.settings.praymodewidget not found
I/PackageManager( 3485): do mInstaller.dexopt : 0
D/PackageManager( 3485): Time to dexopt: 1.389 seconds
W/System.err( 3485): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/app/com.TestApp.Test-1: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
W/System.err( 3485):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
W/System.err( 3485):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
W/System.err( 3485):    at android.content.pm.PackageParser.getHashValueOfPackage(PackageParser.java:5170)
W/System.err( 3485):    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.saveHash(PackageManagerService.java:19974)
W/System.err( 3485):    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.access$5800(PackageManagerService.java:352)
W/System.err( 3485):    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$21.run(PackageManagerService.java:19959)
W/System.err( 3485): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
W/System.err( 3485):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:446)
W/System.err( 3485):    ... 5 more
W/System.err( 3485): remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/system/packages.xml.bak
W/System.err( 3485): remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml.bak
D/PackageManager( 3485): New package installed
```

Though the application then installs successfully but there are rendering issue's when i start the app.

In-case you need some other information on the error let me know.

Comment: This seems crucial `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/app/com.TestApp.Test-1: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
`

Comment: @Danielson yeah, but what i don't understand is why after throwing this error, it successfully installs the application as well. `D/PackageManager( 3485): New package installed`